# How to use magento UI library in custom _module.less file?

Tags: magento2, less-css

I have created module specific less file in magento according to guide at below location.

> app/code/Modulenamespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less

Now I want to be able use magento 2 default ui library inside **_module.less** file. So how can I add reference to _lib.less file so that I can use all available mixins and variables inside my **_module.less**?

I know I can do that in _extend.less but how to in case of **_module.less** Currently 
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`gives error when using library.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution has been found as I had defined my new variable and mixins in _extend.less and _module.less was not able to use those variables and therefore I was getting errors.**

Comment: what error are you getting? and which reference of library you want to use?

Comment: In my _extend.less I defined my new breakpoint @new-breakpoint:959px and therefore  _module.less was not able to access _extend.less and I had to redefine this variable to solve the error.

Comment: please share your path of _extend.less with the variable

Comment: my _extend.less is in app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/source/ folder and _module.less is in app/code.. as mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

I can use magento UI library in **_module.less** but not my custom new variables (e.g.declared for new breakpoints and so on) in **_extend.less**.

Now as **_module.less** is imported though `@magento_import` directive and therefore all files named **_module.less** from all modules will be imported but it has no connection with _extend.less file because in hierarchy _extend.less is imported at last.